# Can I use go-gorm with MySQL json type field?

Tags: go-gorm

I am trying to use Gorm as ORM with MySQL 8.0.22 for data type JSON. Does GORM support this to bind to the struct?

Comment: `string` seems to work, when save to mysql.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the helper datatypes package https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes, which contains a JSON type that is compatible with MySQL, among other databases.